# matplotlib has no attribute 'pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can import matplotlib but when I try to run the following:

```
matplotlib.pyplot(x)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
       matplotlib.pyplot(x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

Answer (score 62):

[`pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) is a submodule of `matplotlib`, but it doesn't get imported with `import matplotlib` only:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>>
```

However, it is recommended to alias it as `plt`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then, you can use the various functions and classes it contains:

```
p = plt.plot(...)
```

Comment: Tried this originally, get an ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/m

Comment: This looks like your installation is corrupt, maybe try a clean reinstall.

Comment: Worked it out.. apparently the current matplotlib version from the installer is not compatible with the 64-bit version of Python so downloaded 32-bit version and works perfectly now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm happy to improve on this answer :-).  Leave a comment about what's wrong and I'll do my best to address it!

Answer (score 44):

Did you import it? Importing `matplotlib` is not enough.

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

but

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
```

works.

pyplot is a submodule of matplotlib and not immediately imported when you import matplotlib.

The most common form of importing pyplot is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Thus, your statements won't be too long, e.g.

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
```

instead of

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
```

And: `pyplot` is not a function, it's a module! So don't call it, use the functions defined **inside** this module instead. See my example above

Comment: Had tried this and it wasn't the problem. Worked it out.. apparently the current matplotlib version from the installer is not compatible with the 64-bit version of Python so downloaded 32-bit version and works perfectly now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Sure, always install the the version of a library corresponding to the version of you interpreter...

Comment: I have the same problem with pyplot. But "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" still doesn't work for me. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer worked for me if you are importing 'librosa' library, just import it before 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'. That worked for me and couple others for similar issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).