# python import will only work in one format

Tags: python, python-import

When i build:

```
import matplotlib
pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4])
pyplot.ylabel('some numbers')
pyplot.show()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Paulair/Desktop/mathGraphing.py", line 2, in <module>
    pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4])
NameError: name 'pyplot' is not defined
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

when i build:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, you need `from matplotlib import pyplot`.

<strike>If you just `import matplotlib`, you'll have to use `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(....`.</strike>

Sorry for the wrong answer, pyplot is a sub-module of matplotlib which deliberately doesn't get imported with a simple `import matplotlib` or `from matplotlib import *`. See [matplotlib has no attribute 'pyplot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812342/matplotlib-has-no-attribute-pyplot).
You have to import it explicitly.

Thx for @Joe Kington's explanation, **the reason for the separation is to:**

1. allow certain setup commands to be called before importing pyplot (e.g. matplotlib.use) and
2. to allow other portions of matplotlib to be used without the "heavy" import of the full plotting functionality. (Mostly #1, though.)

Comment: but is it possible to just import the entire library by saying: import matplotlib? or do you always have to put (from) and (import) everywhere?

Comment: To import everything you could use `from matplotlib import *`. This will pull in all the names from `matplotlib`. You'll have to see if that is a good idea.

Comment: i just tried it, and it doesn't work when use matplotlib.pyplot.plot and so on

Comment: For various reasons, doing `import matplotlib` or `from matplotlib import *` _deliberately does not_ import `matplotlib.pyplot`.  Therefore, you need to explicitly import `matplotlib.pyplot` in some way (e.g. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, `from matplotlib import pyplot`, etc).  The reason for the separation is to 1) allow certain setup commands to be called before importing `pyplot` (e.g. `matplotlib.use`) and 2) to allow other portions of matplotlib to be used without the "heavy" import of the full plotting functionality.  (Mostly #1, though.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just how imports work. When you `import module`, you import just the *name* `module`. If you want to use items or submodules within that module, you need to either:

1. indicate that the names you are using are contained within a certain module by *qualifying* the name: `module.submodule.function(...)`
2. or import the name of the submodule that you want, giving it an alias if you prefer: `import module.submodule` or `import module.submodule as submodule`
3. or import the module/function/class names that you wish to use in the first place: `from module import submodule` or `from module.submodule import function`

Otherwise, Python has no way to know where a certain undefined name might actually exist, so it raises `NameError`.

---

In your particular case, you **must** import `pyplot` explicitly, because `matplotlib` [does not import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812396/2069350) that particular submodule itself (among other [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21993097/2069350), you might notice that `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` takes a while to execute: it's an expensive import, and `matplotlib` chooses to avoid doing it by default since the core functionality doesn't require `pyplot`). So you need to import it explicitly, using some variation on method `2` or `3` above.

Comment: when i use this code, it doesn't work__________________
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4])
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('some numbers')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()

Comment: @fifteenthfret That's because [`matplotlib` doesn't pull in all the `pyplot` functionality by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812396/2069350). In your specific case, you must use one of the second two import options (I've edited this answer to explain).