# 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3

I tried to import `matplotlib.pyplot`, but it keeps telling me that 'module' object has no attribute `pyplot`.

I attached two screenshot below.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBdrR.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLUn0.png)

It used to work perfect well. But since last week, this is not working. 
I am sure I already install matplotlib, because I can import matplotlib.

I am using sublime to edit.

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add code as text and not as pictures, otherwise I cannot be found by search engines and people are less likely to be able to help.

Comment: Hi! I just try to do import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. But it tells me that 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812342/matplotlib-has-no-attribute-pyplot).