# changes to module object before `import`-statement?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import

If I do

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.colorbar
```

-> since colorbar is a submodule and not an attribute, I get the error:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'colorbar'

whereas if I do (add another import before that):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.colorbar
```

it works, I get the

> module 'matplotlib.colorbar'

How is this possible!? I mean, I see, that `colorbar` is a valid attribute of `plt`, but how does it get into the `mpl`? Why can something *before* the import in the second line modify the `mpl` object which is overwritten in my `locals()` *after* that?!
Even if this is matplotlib-specific, it seems my general understanding of python needs an update :)

It does not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib has no attribute 'pyplot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812342/matplotlib-has-no-attribute-pyplot)

Comment: Edited, hopefully to clarify why the linked question about the submodule/attribute-confusion does not explain the magic happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following file structure.

[image]

We have two packages `aaa` and `bbb`. `bbb` has a submodule, `submodule.py`.
The content of the files:

**`aaa/__init__.py`**:

```
import bbb.submodule
print("package aaa init")
```

**`bbb/__init__.py`**:

```
print("package bbb init")
```

**`bbb/submodule.py`**:

```
print("submodule loaded")
```

If we now run `test.py`  with the following lines

```
import bbb
print(bbb.submodule)
```

we get an error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'submodule'
```

because the submodule has not been loaded yet.

However, if we change `text.py` to import `aaa` as well, which itself imports the submodule of `bbb`

```
import aaa
import bbb
print(bbb.submodule)
```

The output will be

```
package bbb init
submodule loaded
package aaa init
<module 'bbb.submodule' from '...\packagestest\bbb\submodule.py'>
```

So in this case, `bbb.submodule` will be found correctly, because it has previously been loaded by the `aaa` package.

Note that the order of imports does not matter here. The following equally works

```
import bbb
import aaa
print(bbb.submodule)
```

Now replace `aaa` with `matplotlib.pyplot`, `bbb` with `matplotlib` and `submodule` with `colorbar` - the effect is the same:
`pyplot` will load `matplotlib.colorbar`, hence it is available as submodule when calling `mpl.colorbar`. In case `pyplot` is not imported, `mpl.colorbar` will not be found.

Comment: aha, thank you. But well ... if I `import aaa`, and inside it there is an `import spam`, then `spam` gets into my namespace? It doesnt normally, does it? Is it some magic with the `__init__.py`?

Comment: also, if I only import `plt`, then `mpl` is not in my namespace (and no mpl.colorbar either, of course). Then after that I import `mpl`, and it gets modified by the import before? Still confusing

Comment: No, spam would not go into your namespace. Also you do not modify anything. You still need to import matplotlib to use matplotlib.colorbar; but because pyplot has already imported matplotlib.colorbar, you will be able to use it. (Also note that all of this is not the recommended way of doing things as it is a source for all kinds of errors.)

Comment: sorry, I still dont get something :) I mean, I see that importing aaa makes the __init__ of bbb to be executed. This is a good point, but I still dont see the connection. I mean, why does the meaning of import bbb in test.py change, compared to not having imported aaa. In one case the bbb-object in my locals() has submodule in its namespace, in the other not. Somehow, the first import changes the impact of the second import on my locals - doesn't it?! ... Maybe this is rather a question for the chat, since it's too misunderstandy here, I'll try :)

Comment: But thank you for your thorough answer with the MWE, this definitely did throw some light on it. But unfortunately, I can't consider it as solved yet and mark it :)

Comment: This is independent of the order. You can first import `bbb` then `aaa`. So, you don't change anything in `bbb`.

Comment: there is no breakthrough yet for me :) and since I'm not usually so toughly understanding, I suspect there is still something hidden... Probably I should read more deeply about import ... seems to be much more complicated than just inserting the code instead of the `import`-statement.

Comment: and concerning the order: in the other order it's less astonishing: if a variable is in the test.py-namespace, it gets modified when assignig to the same name in an inner scope. Not so in the other order.

Comment: Well, if you think of it as "inserting the code", it's even more obvious. `import matplotlib; matplotlib.colorbar` throws an error, while `import.matplotlib.colorbar; import matplotlib; matplotlib.colorbar` does not.

Comment: No it's not ;) because I would not need the second import of matplotlib in order to use matplotlib.colorbar :P anyway, thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

[Answer to similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812342/matplotlib-has-no-attribute-pyplot)

All in all, importing just `matplotlib` is not enough. What you also have to do is to `import pyplot` since its a submodule from `matplotlib` and not a function (you can't call it).

You see that if you just `import matplotlib` but not `pyplot` and then trying to call `pyplot` from the console. you get the same error message. I agree that it is a little bit counterintuitive, but you have to `import pyplot` as a part of `matplotlib` extra in order to allow the calling of functions that are ONLY a part of the submodule and not the main module. In this case, since there is no `colorbar` in `matplotlib` but only in `pyplot`, you have to `import` both modules.

Comment: yes, the question is somehow similar, I'll edit it to make it more distinct

Comment: I hope I could clarify the difference, that my amazement is still quite distinct from that question. But indeed I was not aware, that this question is connected, and it helped me a little in this clarification, thank you.