# Why does Python importing behave like that?

Tags: python

Accessing `pyplot` *after* importing the whole `matplotlib` namespace:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.pyplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

Importing `pyplot` *right away*:

```
In [3]: from matplotlib import pyplot

In [4]: pyplot
Out[4]: <module 'matplotlib.pyplot' from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py'>
```

And that works now. What gives?

I would also appreciate if someone came up with a better name for the question.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812342/matplotlib-has-no-attribute-pyplot

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).